# Why can't we overload a constructor to add a default argument to it

Tags: c++, constructor

Let's consider the following examples:

I.

```
#include <iostream>

struct X {
    X(){ };
    X(const X&, int i = 6);
};

X::X(const X& x, int i) { std::cout << "ctor" << std::endl; }

X x;

X z = x;

int main()
{ 

}
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c663dca3561da29d)**

II.

```
#include <iostream>

struct X {
    X(){ };
    X(const X&, int i);
};

X::X(const X& x, int i = 7) { std::cout << "ctor" << std::endl; } //error:
//addition of default argument on redeclaration makes this constructor a copy constructor

X x;

X z = x;

int main()
{ 

}
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eed1a2195429ceba)**

III

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(int i);
void bar(int j = 7);

void foo(int i = 7){ }
void bar(int j){ }

int main()
{ 

}
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4524a2538f157440)**

Examples I and II are well-formed. But why can't we overload a constructor in the same way as a function (Example II)? How does the Standard prevent it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that whether a class is trivial, or trivially copyable, etc., should really be decidable based on the class definition and not require knowledge of the whole program. §8.3.6 [dcl.fct.default]/p6 (quoting N4140):

> Except for member functions of class templates, the default arguments
>   in a member function definition that appears outside of the class
>   definition are added to the set of default arguments provided by the
>   member function declaration in the class definition; **the program is
>   ill-formed if a default constructor (12.1), copy or move constructor,
>   or copy or move assignment operator (12.8) is so declared**.

See [CWG issue 1344](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1344).

Comment: Where did you find N4140? That link http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4140.pdf is broken.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv The github repo.

Answer (score 0):

You can overload constructors in the same way as functions. The problem with sample II is that the compiler can't see the difference between

```
X::X(const X& x) //The copy constructor
```

and

```
X::X(const X& x, int i = 7) //A normal constructor
```

in your case : `X z = x;`

That's because the compiler expands it to `X z(x);`, which could be the normal or the copy constructor.